# Simple HTML contact details form with table

Tags: html

These are my first steps in FE so please don't hate me. I want to create a page with user details.

What I have is something below:

```
First name:      Last name:      User status:      Date joined:    Policies accepted:
John             Doe             active            12.12.2021      true
```

To do so I used `table` but below that table I need to display user contact details:

```
Contact details
Email:                        Phone number:
example@example.com           +681234123412
```

Is there a better way to display such a thing than `table` or it is a common approach in such situations ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use forms instead of table for the user details and the contact details, it's much more effective, productive, and easier.

Comment: You mean this forms https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp ?

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: No, you didn't. `An HTML form is used to collect user input. The user input is most often sent to a server for processing.` - I want to display user data, not collect data from him.

Comment: So I didn't understand what did you mean. Can you explain it again?

Comment: I want to create a page to display user details, data comes from DB, other requirements are in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name:</th>
        <th>Last Name:</th>
        <th>User Status:</th>
        <th>Date Joined:</th>
        <th>Policies Accepted:</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>Active</td>
        <td>12.12.2021</td>
        <td>True</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">Contact Details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Email:</td>
        <td colspan="2">Phone Number:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">example@example.com</td>
        <td colspan="2">+681234123412</td>
    </tr>
    
</tfoot>
```

Here's the screen shot example.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJSqN.jpg

Comment: Contact Details should be a separate table but I see what you mean. Let's assume that `Contact Details` will be a separate table, how do I not display this table all over the page?